# How to print the hyperlink ONCE?

Tags: php

These are my tables:

1.**topics** table:

```
topic_id            subject         
   1                 bla bla      
   2                 two two
```

2 **contents** table:

```
content_id          topic_id        content                     date
   1                   1             subject description       7/10/2014
   2                   1             reply1                    7/12/2014
   3                   1             reply2                    8/1/2014
```

As you can see, the `topic_id` in the *content* table is the foreign key of the *topics* table. The `content` column in the *contents* table store the description/ content of the topic (`topic_id # 1, for instance`) **as well as** the *repli(es)* (content_ids # 2, #3) of the typical topic_id #1 too. So, in order to print out the `subject` once, I code like this:

```
$printsubjectonce = FALSE; // Flag variable.

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    if (!$printsubjectonce) {

    echo "{$row['subject']}\n"; //subject is printed ONCE

         $printsubjectonce = TRUE;

    }

    //print the content:
    echo "{$row['content']} <br />({$row['date']}\n"; //The subject description and possible repli(es) are repeatedly printed

}// End of WHILE loop.
```

Everything is okay. Now I would like to add a *delete* hyperlink below the **subject content**, *but not below the subject line*. Then, I add `<a href="delete.com"> Delete </a>` below the `$row['content']`. However, the output shows that the *delete* hyperlink(s) is/are repeatedly printed out in according with the possible number of repli(es) the subject has got. However, what I wish is to have the *hyperlink* printed out **only once** (below the subject description) in spite of how many repli(es) the subject would have.

I also tried moving the `<a href=...> into the`if (!$printsubjectonce){...}', just above the code `$printsubjectonce = TRUE;`, it is then *logically* printed out above the content section, which i didn't want to.

And I got stuck here now. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this;

```
<?php

if (!defined('CODE_EXECUTED')) {
    YOUR_CODE_HERE
    define('CODE_EXECUTED', TRUE);
}

?>
```

You can then place the delete button where ever you like; you can use something like this to print the delete button once:

```
 echo "{$row['content']}" . ((!defined('delButton'))?"<a href='delete.com'> Delete </a>":"") . " <br />({$row['date']}\n";
 define('delButton', TRUE);
```

That will make the delete button print out once, supposedly. test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use two `if` statements. The first one is for printing the subject heading, the second one is for printing the delete link. Put the `$printsubjectonce = true` assignment after the second one.

```
$printsubjectonce = FALSE; // Flag variable.

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // Print subject header once
    if (!$printsubjectonce) {
        echo "{$row['subject']}\n";
    }
    //print the content:
    echo "{$row['content']} <br />({$row['date']}\n"; //The subject description and possible repli(es) are repeatedly printed
    // Print delete link once
    if (!$printsubjectonce) {
        echo '<a href="delete.com"> Delete </a>';
        $printsubjectonce = TRUE;
    }

}// End of WHILE loop.
```